# Expo eas: Android build fails if I run a prebuild before

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas, expo-build

I use Expo 46.

I would like to change some config in my `AndroidManifest` so I run an `npx expo prebuild` that generates an android folder without error.

But then my `eas build` is not working anymore (it is if I don't run `prebuild`).
I get this error:

```
Failed to find 'build.gradle' file for project: /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app.
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Run the `npx expo-updates` in the root of your project in order to update the `build.gradle` file with the necessary changes.

By the way, as I saw your remarks under the other posts: The `expo prebuild` command generates an Android project in the `android` directory, which contains the `build.gradle` file that is used by the `expo build:android` command. The `eas build` command is a shorthand for the `expo build:android` command, so it expects the Android project to be present in the `android` directory.

If you run `expo prebuild` and then `eas build`, the `eas build` command should be able to find the `build.gradle` file and build the Android app successfully.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not able to find build.gradle after expo prebuild, that's the problem :(

Comment: what version of eas-cli do you have installed and are you using npm, yarn or pnpm? I've been using yarn 1.22 since last May for my current project and installed eas-cli globally 'yarn global add eas-cli' and whenever I get/got a a 'newer version of eas-cli' notification I did 'yarn global remove eas-cli' followed by 'yarn global add eas-cli' as the global upgrade function never worked for me (or I was doing it wrong - probably). This probably doesn't help you much but someone  else might benefit. VERY important in your eas.json specify a higher range "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.0.0" for ^4

Comment: also, what version of expo are you using (I'm on expo sdk 48) - might also make a difference?
Are you installing expo-cli as well as eas-cli as since Expo 46 Expo is using Local Expo cli npx expo ... which I think you're using but maybe make sure you're not also installing expo-cli and using that for some things and not others - can get confusing sometimes when there are updates that alter your normal workflow

Answer (score 0):

Try running the `expo prebuild` command with the `--clear` flag, which will clear any existing pre-build files before generating the new ones.

This should ensure that the generated android folder includes the `build.gradle` file, and the `eas build` command should be able to use this file to build the app.

```
npx expo prebuild --clean
```

Alternatively, you can try running the eas build command without running the expo prebuild command first. This will use the original Android project files in your app, which should include the build.gradle file and allow the eas build command to work correctly.

How to run the eas build command without running expo prebuild first:

```
npx eas build
```

Comment: I know I could use npx eas build but I need to modify native files

Comment: I'm trying with the clean option (it's apparently clean not clear)

Comment: It does not work, I still get the same error