# Expo: eas build blockedPermissions does not work

Tags: android, expo, android-manifest, eas, expo-build

I'm trying to remove a permission that I don't need that is blocking my submission to the App Store: `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`

I use `Expo 46` and I put

```
"android": {
      "blockedPermissions": ["android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"],
```

in my `app.json` file.

When I run an expo prebuild I'm able to see the permission removed in the generated `AndroidManifest`. However, when I run an eas build (locally or not) if I decompile with bundletool the aab generated, the `AndroidManifest` does not show this line removing the permission.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can simply add `"expo": { "android": { "package": "com.my.app", "permissions": ["REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"] } }` to your app.json file to remove the **REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES** permission from your app.

Comment: No it does not work like this anymore in expo 45+

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an issue with how Expo is handling the `blockedPermissions` configuration in your app.json file. It appears that Expo is not applying this configuration when building the app with the `eas build` command.

## Solution One

One possible solution is to use the `expo build:android` command instead of the `eas build` command. This command will build your app using Expo's build service, which may handle the `blockedPermissions` configuration correctly. You can then use the generated `.aab` file to submit your app to the App Store.

## Solution Two

Another solution is to manually remove the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission from the `AndroidManifest.xml` file before building the app. You can do this by editing the file and removing the following line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Once you have removed this line, you can run the `eas build` command to build your app, and the generated `.aab` file should not include the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission.

Comment: If I prebuild the app with expo-prebuild I get an error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74560557/expo-eas-android-build-fails-if-i-run-a-prebuild-before) thus cannot use this solution. expo build:android would work but "expo build:android will be discontinued on January 4, 2023"

Comment: I'm going to attempt to answer that question, and then hopefully you can use this solution.